# seaborn multiple lines in a Lineplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a dataframe looks like the following:

| location | 1/1/21 | 1/2/21 | 1/3/21 | another_var |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 13 | 15 | 18 | 0.25 |
| B | 1 | 4 | 4 | 0.28 |
| C | 3 | 3 | 3 | 0.3 |

location column is the index column
How can I make a seaborn lineplot with three lines (A, B, C) and dates on the x-axis? I tried to do df.columns but I don't know how to exclude the last column (since it's not a date column)

Answer (score 0):

You melt a subset of the dataframe to give you something in the long format:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'1/1/21':[13,1,3],"1/2/21":[15,4,3],"1/3/21":[18,4,3],
"another_var":[0.25,0.28,0.3]},index=["A","B","C"])

df.iloc[:,:-1].reset_index().melt(id_vars="index")

    index   variable    value
0   A   1/1/21  13
1   B   1/1/21  1
2   C   1/1/21  3
3   A   1/2/21  15
4   B   1/2/21  4
5   C   1/2/21  3
6   A   1/3/21  18
7   B   1/3/21  4
8   C   1/3/21  3
```

And you plot this:

```
sns.lineplot(data = df.iloc[:,:-1].reset_index().melt(id_vars="index"),
             x = "variable" , y = "value" , hue = "index")
```

[image]